# Persist Background Process Limit setting

Tags: settings

Is it possible to persist the Background Process Limit setting? It's lost upon reboot and reverts to Standard Limit.

Settings \ Developer Options \ Background process limit

Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not think its meant for persisting... See [Dianne Hackborn's comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/DuiStnPN9Yg)

Also had a mosey around the ICS source code found in `packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java`

Source code to the related screen, found on [Android's github](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java).

By looking for the variable that is associated with *Settings* > *Developer Options* > ***Background Process Limit*** ([see](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java#L103) *line number* ***103***)  and ([See](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java#L215) *line number* ***215***) called `mAppProcessLimit`.

With that in mind, keep looking further down in the source, the routine that is responsible for saving the settings for this particular screen called `onPreferenceTreeClick`.

That is, in programming parlance, called a "*listener*" that is monitoring the changes made on that screen and writes it out immediately to the backing store by Android. ([See](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/DevelopmentSettings.java#L790) between *line numbers* ***790*** and ***858***)

Unfortunately, the "*listener*", in this case, does not have a reference to the persisting/saving of the value for that variable `mAppProcessLimit`; which is what the OP is experiencing, set it for the duration of when the handset is alive, then upon reboot, it gets lost.

In short, you cannot do anything about this as that is built straight from the oven, and bundled onto your handset, but with that in mind, you can roll-your-own-custom ROM variant of ICS with a modified version of the source to do that.

Comment: Any updates to this in newer versions of Android?

Answer (score 3):

I have written a small android app that can be used to set the process limit by using Java Reflection to access the internal API. On Android 4.0 you don't even need to install it as a system app. This is required for Android 4.2 or so onward.

https://github.com/flode/SetAndroidProcessLimit

Thank you @t0mm13b for the internal API reference ;)